# Code randomly doesn't follow instructions of For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am attempting to create a program that finds the number of possible configurations using factorials. Here is my code so far:

```
from collections import Counter
letters = []
lettnum = []
trash = []
booleans = []
boolet = {}
def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fact(n - 1)

word = input("Word: ")
x = fact(len(word))
for char in word:
    letters.append(char)

z = Counter(letters)
y = list(z.values())
ans = "print("
print(letters)
print(y)

for element in y:
    if y[0] == element:
        ans = ans + str(fact(element))
    else:
        ans = ans + "*" + str(fact(element))
ans = ans + ")"
print(ans)
```

If you enter the word `tool`, it is supposed to give an answer of

```
print(1*2*1)
```

but instead prints out

```
print(1*1*21*1)
```

I've noticed that it combines the 2 and 1 without adding a `*`, and it also adds random `1`'s for absolutely no reason. What's up with my code?

Some more info:

- Text editor: Visual Studio Code
- Python Version: Python 3.7.3

Comment: use `for i,element in enumerate(y):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the goal your program is trying to accomplish however I do see the issue of the behavior you are seeing

Your issue lies in how you are checking the first element

Notice this line is checking that element is == 1

```
    if y[0] == element:
```

The last element is also 1 so it goes along the same path

A solution to this would be to write the loop like this

```
ans = "print(" + str(fact(y[0]))

for element in y[1:]:
        ans += "*" + str(fact(element))
ans = ans + ")"
print(ans)
```